# In Matlab, how to scan a binary image in 2D co-ordinate system that is 45 degrees rotated to actual co-ordinate system?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a binary image as in figure below,

[image]

the x-y co-ordinate system is the default co-ordinate system that comes with MATLAB. I am able to get the sum of pixels across each row and column in x-y co-ordinate system.

But I want the sum of pixels by stepping through u-v co-ordinate system. How can i get it?

My idea is to

1) Convert the x-y co-ordinate system to a continuous (real valued) co-ordinate system
2) Find the points in x-y coordinates corresponding to each point in u-v co-ordinate system. like (1,1) in u-v corresponds to (1.26,1.45) in x-y.
3) Get sum of rows and columns in u-v co-ordinate.

In this regard, 
1) what are the methods to create a spatial co-ordinate system and convert pixel coordinate system to spatial coordinate system?
2) how to get the values of fractional pixels in the spatial co-ordinate system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only want the diagonals at exactly 45 degrees, and your pixels are square (safe assumption with most standard cameras), then you don't really need to do any coordinate transformation I don't think.  You can use the fact that all of the points along the diagonals have the form e.g. `I(ix, ix), I(1 + ix, ix)`.  Working out the limits is a bit tricky.  Try this for the "column" (diagonal from the top left to the bottom right) sums, starting at the bottom left, moving up the left edge, then across the top:

```
I = eye(5, 4);
I(4, 1) = 1;

[nrows, ncols] = size(I);
colsums = zeros(nrows + ncols - 1, 1);

% first loop over each row in the original image except the first one
for ix = nrows : -1 : 2,
    JX = [0 : min(nrows - ix, min(nrows-1, ncols-1))];
    for jx = JX,
        colsums(nrows - ix + 1) = colsums(nrows - ix + 1) + I(ix + jx, jx + 1);
    end
end

% then loop over each column in the original image 
for ix = 1 : ncols,
    JX = [0 : min(nrows - ix - 1, min(nrows-1, ncols-1))];
    for jx = JX,
        colsums(nrows + ix - 1) = colsums(nrows + ix - 1) + I(1 + jx, ix + jx);
    end
end
```

Note that if the *distance* matters to you (kind of sounds like it doesn't), then the distances along these diagonals are `sqrt(2)/2` longer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is exactly what the "radon" function does. This helped me in understanding things that I was not understanding in "radon" function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the radon transform for the angles 45,135.
It will give you **exactly** what you need.
The sum of pixels in a specific angle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

```
I = checkerboard(10,10);
figure;imshow(I)
R = radon(I,[45 135]);
figure;plot(R(:,1))
```

Here are some images that explain Radon transform

[image: Image taken from wikipedia]

[image: Image taken from Matlab help]

Comment: Thanks. I did figure out that the earlier answer was a radon implementation. But I was messing around with the units. The 1/sqrt(2) length and the implementation myself gave me a clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `meshgrid` to produce a coordinate system for the image. You can rotate this coordinate system by matrix-multiplication with a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). This should give you transformed coordinates, but you need values from them and as you said they will be fractional pixels. It's up to you to determine the best way to interpolate. One method is to just use the value of the nearest pixel (aka nearest neighbor). Linear interpolation will typically give a better result - take the neighboring pixels and sum them up, weighted by how close they are to your target coordinate. I would only bother with higher-order interpolation methods if the results are unsatisfactory.

---

An alternative to your proposed method would be to use `imrotate` to transform the image with a 45-degree rotation, then calculate the line integral (sum) of the vertical pixels in the column you are interested in.

Comment: the problem with the "imrotate" method is that, it introduces blank pixels as result of rotation. line integral sum gives misleading information because of these blank pixels introduced in the edges.

Comment: But the blank pixels will not affect the summation as they are all zero.

Comment: Will affect my calculation, since I am interested in the row and column with minimum pixel value. Since the "imrotate" introduced blank rows and column, which would become my minimum row/column.